# How to get the function which caused a DOM mutation with a MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am currently trying to figure out which function modified the DOM using a `MutationObserver`. The following snippet unfortunately doesn't work (the stack trace seems to be empty).

```
var targetNode = document.body;
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
      // The trace unfortunatelly doesn't contain the function 
      // "addSomeElement", which I am trying to receive at this point.
      console.trace(); 
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

which is followed by some DOM mutation:

```
function addSomeElement() {
  targetNode.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
}
addSomeElement();
```

Is there any way how I could output the function which does the actual mutation call (in this case the `appendChild`)?

Comment: Assuming you want to automate it, you can hook all or most of the node mutation prototype methods like appendChild and then analyze `new Error().stack` or simply invoke console.trace()

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, that's a great idea! I am going to try that.

Answer (score 9):

Use a DOM breakpoint (should work in Chrome and Firefox)

Developer Tools
-> Inspector
-> Right click on the element you want to monitor
-> Break on: Subtree modifications

When the child elements of the selected node are changed the browser will break on the responsible piece of JavaScript.

[image: Adding DOM breakpoint]

Comment: Thanks! Are you by chance aware of any way to add conditions to such a break point?

Comment: You can only select the monitored element and the type of modification (subtree, attributes). Something else is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

`MutationObserver` returns the `MutationRecord` which only describes the changes themselves.

It doesn't provide information about how those changes were effected.

Comment: Thanks! Are you aware of any alternatives?

Comment: Nope, but check @Andreas answer above.

Comment: Adding console.trace in the handler may help you find what triggered it.